# Running tests with Karma on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, karma-runner

I cannot get my unit tests to run on IE8.

I am testing an angular directive which has a dependency on JQuery and I am using Karma as the test runner.

The tests run as expected on Chrome, but when I try to run them on IE8 I am getting an error "Object does not support this property or method." I opened the jQuery at the location specified and it turns out that the 'property or method' IE is not happy about is the `addEventListener` method on the document. It is happening before any tests are run during test run initialization process.

AFAIK Prior to IE9 the corresponding method was called `attachEventListener`, but I would assume that jQuery would know that. So my only hypothesis at this time is that I somehow tricked jQuery into thinking that it is not IE8 it is dealing with.

Any thoughts? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you're running jQuery 2.x.

jQuery comes in two branches today:

- 1.x - This is the older branch which runs on old and new browsers from IE6 up.
- 2.x - This is the newer rewrite which is smaller and faster but only runs on newer browsers, they support IE9+. see [this release note](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/).

> jQuery 2.0 has arrived!
>
> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility often causes problems of its own.

Luckily, the latest jQuery 2.x is (at least at the moment) fully interchangeable with the latest jQuery 1.x so you *supposedly* can make the switch seamlessly.

<sup>And just for the record it's `attachEvent` in IE8 ;)</sup>

Comment: Nope I run jquery 1.9.1

Comment: My apologies. You were right - my sample code was referring to JQ 1.9.1, but somehos the karma conf was pointing to the 2.0. Silly me